# FB access token

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have implemented facebook into my web app. However, this one error keeps showing up (when facebook is not in active use).An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

```
An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
```

Here is my Facebook JS:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function()
{
FB.init({
appId      : '<?php echo AppInfo::appID(); ?>',
channelUrl : "<?php //echo URL.'scripts/facebook/channel.php'; ?>",
status     : false,
cookie     : true,
xfbml      : false
});

FB.api('/me',function(){});

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {

if (response.status === 'connected')
{
    window.location.replace("<?php echo Router::$url; ?>");
}
else if (response.status === 'not_authorized')
{
    FB.login(function(response){}, {scope:'email'});
}
else
{
    FB.login(function(response){}, {scope:'email'});
}

});
};

(function(d, s, id)
{
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id))
{
    return;
};
js = d.createElement(s);
js.id = id;
js.src = "<?php echo URL.'scripts/facebook/all.js'; ?>";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}
(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

I searched the web and found the `FB.api()`. Unfortunatelly, it doesn't help...

Comment: You can not query the API for `/me` without having the user connect to your app first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your call to `FB.api` inside the callback to `FB.getLoginStatus`, and then only execute it if the user is actually connected.

Also, you cannot call `FB.login` outside of an event triggered by the user, such as a click event.

Answer (score 0):

You must generate an access token. The access token tells Facebook which user you want and gives you permission to make requests on their behalf.

You can [manually generate one](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer). Or, you can add the authentication process for Javascript which can be [found here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/getting-started-web/).